# Mailchimp - Signup Form - Using Tags

Tags: forms, mailchimp, newsletter, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I've been using 'Groups' selection in my Mailchimp signup forms.

But is it possible to use 'Tags' in the same way?

I've got a MC signup form embedded on my site and wondering if I can replace the 'Groups' with 'Tags', so the new subscribers would be tagged right away?